# Brcypt algo pre-requisite

Tags: java, spring-security

can we use bcrypt algo with jdk 7 and spring security version 3.0
I couldn't find any method that can use brcypt.

Also, if someone can help me in this question as an alternate([issues in migrating from md5 to bcypt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76439617/21858148))

Comment: the crypto module was added in spring security 3.1 https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#crypto